# Does CLR add overhead fields to type which value is null?

Tags: c#, string, memory-management, heap-memory, clr

I am getting familiar with CLR and I wonder if I write in my code something like that:

```
String s = null;
```

Does CLR allocate memory in address space by reserving some space and adding overhead fields and without any value?

I was trying to find answers in the book CLR via C# but failed

Comment: That statement _declares_ a variable of type `string` and initializes it to `null`. The `string` type is a _reference type_. References to instances of a reference type are all the same size (4 bytes in 32 bit programs, 8 bytes in 64 bit). The compiler will allocate space in the current _stack frame_ for that reference. When the method (/function) returns, the stack frame is abandoned.  If you hadn't initialized the variable the reference would still be there. if you had initialized it to an instance of a string, the memory in the managed heap_ would have been allocated (with flags, etc.)

Comment: "If you hadn't initialized the variable the reference would still be there" unless it will be never used and jit/aot compiler decides to remove it

Comment: I think you should clarify first what it allocates when it's *not* null. Then you will realize that in this case there is only the pointer space, which is the same whether it's null or not.

Comment: So, type object pointer pointing to null will still take 32 bits and another 32 for sync block index (32bit app)? So a type variable with null value will take a little bit of memory anyway?

Comment: @BestSnowWitch. No, the variable will take 32 (/64) bits in the current stack frame. An instance of an object (of reference type) gets all the object goodness (like sync block stuff). A variable initialized to `null` doesn't point to an object; it's effectively empty.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know! Many thanks!